# JSON Error says " Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':' "

Tags: json

I'm trying to have this discord bot working and it's giving an error

```
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'
```

I don't understand what the issue is with this JSON. I have attached the entire JSON below

```
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "WordleEdit is a multiplayer version of Wordle (created by Josh Wardle) where players can edit their own words as they go. It runs as a Discord bot! I programmed the bot in February 2022 and played it with friends in March 2022, but for some reason I never released the source code until now. Well, here it is!",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository" {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/carykh/WordleEdit.git"
  }
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/carykh/WordleEdit/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/carykh/WordleEdit#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^14.6.0"
  }
}

}
```

Comment: Your json is not valid , I can't see the beginning, Pls recheck and post the real one

Answer (score 1):

Check your json with https://jsonlint.com/, becasue your json isn't in a correct  format

Following maybe helpful

```
{
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "WordleEdit is a multiplayer version of Wordle (created by Josh Wardle) where players can edit their own words as they go. It runs as a Discord bot! I programmed the bot in February 2022 and played it with friends in March 2022, but for some reason I never released the source code until now. Well, here it is!",
"main": "main.js",
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/carykh/WordleEdit.git"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/carykh/WordleEdit/issues"
},
"homepage": "https://github.com/carykh/WordleEdit#readme",
"dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^14.6.0"
}
}
```

Comment: I did that but it only says  " Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':' " I don't understand what it means what I should add so it doesn't say that

Comment: @SadCoder I have post a json which follow the format. Please also check the basic format of json so you can edit correctly.